# Connect Webservice through XML

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.56/AMSP/AMSPWS.asmx"];

NSString *soapMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                   "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                   "<soap:Body>"
                   "<PostXMLStr xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                   "<cust>%@</cust>"
                   "<tran>%@</tran>"
                   "<ret>%@</ret>"
                   "<ppay>%@</ppay>"
                   "<recp>%@</recp>"
                   "<sCode>%@</sCode>"
                   "<companyShortName>%@</companyShortName>"
                   "<companyCode>%@</companyCode>"
                   "</PostXMLStr>"
                   "</soap:Body>"
                   "</soap:Envelope>",cust,trans,RETURNS,prepayment,receipt,spcode1,companyShortName,companyCode];


NSMutableURLRequest *requests = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                    timeoutInterval:5];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMsg length]];
[requests setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[requests addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requests addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[requests addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/PostXMLStr" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[requests setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData   *data =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requests returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *stringSoap;

stringSoap = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
```

I am new to connect WebService through objective C. I do not know how to check XML is connected to WebService. When I print stringSoap, I am not getting any value. I do not know is this correct way to calling XML. How to check XML is connected to WebService or not. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all what you are requesting is not `XML` its `SOAP` webservice call, so make sure you are doing it correctly. whether you webservice read XML or Encoded Data?

Comment: put your server side script here for review if possible.

Comment: not possible to give it.Is there wrong with SOAP webservice call?

Comment: doesn't seem any problem with SOAP request, but may be encoding with response, just try this code to encode your response data  NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data mutableBytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(theXML);

Answer (score 0):

As you are new, this will help u to convert SOAP service to ObjectiveC
[sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com/)
[wsdl2objc](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)